# How do I make a process that checks if the user only entered numbers and floating points?

Tags: python

i am doing a process that see what in your cpf, and your cpf needs to have 14 characters, like that "111.111.111-11", but even if i put "pppppppppppppp", the user can pass

i tried this

```
pedro = True
while pedro:
        cpff =input('Digite seu cpf aqui: ')
        
        if len(cpff) > digitos:
            
            print('cpf inválido')
        elif len(cpff) < digitos:
            print('cpf inválido')
        elif len(cpff) == digitos:
            find = input('O que desejas encontrar em seu cpf? ')
            break
```

but this is a faulty method, so after that i tried this

```
digitos = 14
pedro = True
while pedro:
        cpff =input('Digite seu cpf aqui: ')
        cpff = float
        if cpff != float:
            print('Digite apenas números e pontos')
        cpff = str
        if len(cpff) > digitos:
            
            print('cpf inválido')
        elif len(cpff) < digitos:
            print('cpf inválido')
        elif len(cpff) == digitos:
            find = input('O que desejas encontrar em seu cpf? ')
            break
```

but still going wrong, and this gave me this error "object of type 'type' has no len()" what i do?

Comment: Would a valid use input _always_ have the format `111.111.111-11`?

Comment: yes, it is, cause is the format i need

Comment: Time to bust out `re`.

Comment: Please provide a more general description of your desired format. Do you want three groups of three digits, separated by a `.` and followed by a `-` and two digits? If so, why do you expect this complicated validation to be done by a simple `len(...) > val`?

Comment: i'm new on python, so this is the form that i think that could be work

Comment: so theoretically how would i do that

Answer (score 3):

I would use `re.search` along with a regex pattern:

```py
import re

while True:
    cpff = input('Digite seu cpf aqui: ')
    if re.search(r'^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}$', cpff):
        break
    else:
        print('cpf inválido')
```

Comment: HOLY JESUS you saved my day, i didnt knew how to do it, tysm!!!!

Comment: If green checkmark to the left is possible, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Using `\d` [will match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-30) any character in the Unicode [numbers, decimal digit category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), which is probably not desired here. Instead you can use the pattern `[0-9]` or use the [ASCII flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII) to limit the match to only the ASCII digits from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

There are other better approaches to solving the problem statement but I guess they would not be easy for you to understand.
I have written the code which would be easiest to understand.

```
# check if CPF is in correct format: "111.111.111-11"

# Indexs            0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
# cpf characters    1 1 1 . 1 1 1 . 1 1 1  -  1  1

entrada_recibida = False

while not entrada_recibida:
    cpf = input('Digite seu cpf aqui:')
    formato_correcto = True

    if len(cpf) != 14:
        formato_correcto = False
    if cpf[3]!= '.' or cpf[7]!= '.':
        formato_correcto = False
    if cpf[11] != '-':
        formato_correcto = False
    '''
    print(cpf[0:3])
    print(cpf[4:7])
    print(cpf[8:11])
    print(cpf[12:])
    '''
    if not cpf[0:3].isdigit() or not cpf[4:7].isdigit() or not cpf[8:11].isdigit() or not cpf[12:].isdigit():
        formato_correcto = False

    if not formato_correcto:
        print('Formato Incorrecto')
    else:
        entrada_recibida = True
        print('Formato Correcto')
```

If you have trouble understanding the last `if` condition, just uncomment the four print statements.

Output:

```
Digite seu cpf aqui:111.111.111-111
Formato Incorrecto
Digite seu cpf aqui:111.111.111.11
Formato Incorrecto
Digite seu cpf aqui:111.A11.111-11
Formato Incorrecto
Digite seu cpf aqui:999.999.999-99
Formato Correcto
```

Comment: I used Google Translate to translate from the English variable name to the Spanish variable name so it could be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You need pythons standard regex module

```
import re

while True:
    cpff = input('Digite seu cpf aqui: ')
    if re.search(r'(\d[0-9]+(.|-)){3}\d[0-9]$', cpff): 
        print('Válido') 
        break
    else: print('cpf inválido')
```

**Explanation :**

```
r'(\d[0-9]+(.|-)){3}\d[0-9]+$'

re.search(r'') - r is reading it as a raw string
\d[0-9]+       - we select digits with range 0 - 9 only
(.|-)          - followed by a . or -
(\d[0-9]+){3}  - the whole sequence we search 3 times
\d[0-9]+$       - then at the end we find 2 digits whose range is 0 to 9
```